# spring boot 2: load application.properties manually

Tags: spring-boot, datasource, startup, application.properties

is it possible to access application.properties values while creating datasource in SpringApplication.run?

I have tried to inject value with @Value but when i need the values, the bean with @ConfigurationProperties is not created yet.

Comment: could you describe more the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

if you are referring to data source url,username and password you can use these keys :

```
spring.datasource.url=your_database_url_and_port_number
spring.datasource.username=your_database_username
spring.datasource.password=your_username_passsword
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add @EnableConfigurationProperties annotation mentioning the properties POJO name.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigurationProperties(ConfigProperties.class)
```

Then in the ConfigProperties class you need to add the below annotation.Prefix is what you will set in the properties file.

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "mail")
public class ConfigProperties {
private String hostName; 
private int port;
private String from;
// standard getters and setters 
}
```

Values in properties file.

```
#Simple properties
mail.hostname=host@mail.com
mail.port=9000
mail.from=mailer@mail.com
```

Comment: You can elaborate your problem statement if this is not what you were looking for.

Comment: i've tried your solution but it doesn't work because the bean ConfigProperties is created after the datasource. So ConfigProperties == null.